# Package installation

Tags: color, packages, installing

Please help me install a package. I've tried and tried, but I don't know what the problem is.

I wanted to install the `xcolor` package, so I downloaded it from CTAN, unzipped it and opened the `ins` file with `cmd`. I got the `sty` file and copied it to `tex/latex/xcolor`, but it still tells me "xcolor missing". I don't know what to do. :(

Comment: you should never need to install xcolor from ctan, just update the package in your miktex or texlive

Comment: I can't instal package from miktex that is why I downoad packages from CTAN.

Comment: do not put it in your miktex input tree, put it in your local tree but I don't know the miktex details but better would be to fix your miktex installation. xcolor is in miktex and installed by default

Comment: I puted it in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor, I think it's the right place.
For miktex, Since I have windows 7, I use Miktex 2.9 I can't downoad package from there, i wish I can,I woudn't wast 3hours for a package.
Sorry for my bad engish, I'm not the best in english and thanks for your answers.

Comment: no that is where _miktex_ would put the version it installed but you should put it somewhere else to avoid confusing miktex. simplest is to simply put it in the same folder as your document. but you shoud fix miktex so you can install packages using its console

Comment: I can use another compiler ?

Comment: Hi @Nika I use MikTex as well on both Xubuntu and Windows 11. When MikTeX can’t install a package it’s mostly a connection problem reaching the distribution server. Did you try changing the distribution server to see of the error persisted?

Comment: It's working finally, thank you @DavidCarlisle. I I puted it somewhere ese like you said. You really helped me thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @alchemist it is a connection problem but I don't know what to do, Mr.David is right, I really need to resolve this problem.please help me, how can I change the distribution server ?

Comment: Do you use the MikTeX Console to install packages and keep them updated? Then open the Console and select the `update`  option (second choice on the left side). In the new window you see `Retrieve from` as first line. Next to that is a selection bar. Default it says "<Random package repository ..>". Press on the dark triangle to see other options, select one of those and press `Change` . Try `Update` next to see if the new connection works. You may need to try it a few times.

Comment: An edit to my previous comment: Press on `Change` . In the popup window, check `Connection settings`. Default `Use proxy` should be not selected. Tab on `Next`. A list of servers appears. Select one and press `Finish`.

Comment: @alchemist the problem is that there is no server appearing.

Comment: Did you check the second comment? I made a mistake in the first, leaving out the appearance of the pop-up window when pressing `Change`. The system would’ve allow me to edit that first comment.

Comment: If you did follow the second comment and no additional repository servers appeared, there might be an issue with allowed traffic on your firewall configuration. It sounds as if MikTeX isn’t allowed to connect to any internet service.

Comment: I think we don't use the same version of MikTex 
I use the 2.9 version, on Windows 7. Update is the third choice and when I select Update
"Random package repository" is already selected (when i click on the dark triangle, there is no other options) .when i press Change, I got three option, I chose the first,then Next,but there is no server appearing.

Comment: This question is now continued under a new one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672906/cant-download-packages-from-miktex . The problem is the discontinuation of support for legacy 32 bit systems announced by MikTeX on Januari 20, 2023.