# Can't download packages from MikTex

Tags: packages, miktex, miktex2.9

I'm using MikTex 2.9 version (32 bit) on windows 7, but it couldn't connect to sever even when I'm connected.

[image: These is no server appearing]

I'm tired of downloading package one by one from CTAN. I hope there is a solution.

Comment: You could check the connection/proxy settings (click on "change" in your screenshot), but windows7 is no longer supported by miktex, so you are basically on your own.

Comment: So i can't download packages from MikTex if I use Windows 7 ?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't use windows 7 for years.

Comment: When I go to the connection settings, therse a box where it's say if I want to use proxy setting, should I select something in this box?

Comment: Sorry but how can I know if you use a proxy?

Comment: if i want to use a proxy server* sorry
and I didn't seect it

Comment: It probably won‘t run on Win7, see here: https://miktex.org/announcement/legacy-windows-deprecation. Message was recently released.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: The announcement was published on January 20, 2023. Now, I am using a laptop about 11 years old (Athlon II X2 processor) and run MikTeX and TeXStudio on it without issues (apart from being a bit on the slow side ...). I use Xubuntu 22.04 64bits. The big question is: what programs do you use on your Windows 7 32 bit, that aren't available under Ubuntu? And then THE question: are you willing to switch to another operating system to continue using your device?